# Flow type checking seems to be off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

In the below code with Flow, I'm getting no errors when running flow even if I change the ID type to string when it is always getting a number from the array of object literals I'm passing to this stateless react component. Am I missing something? It seems as if Flow isn't really checking my types of the object item.

```
type Item = {
  item: {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    category: string,
    description: string,
    link: string,
    release_date: string,
    views: string,
    image: string,
 }
}

// beggining of my react stateless component
const Single = (({ item }: Item ) =>
<li className="col l6 s12">
  <div className="card">
    <div className="card-image">
      <img src={item.image} alt={item.title} />
    </div>
    <div className="card-content">
      <span className="card-title">{item.title}</span>
      <p>{item.description}</p>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col l6 center">
          <blockquote><h5>Released: {item.release_date}</h5></blockquote>
        </div>
        <div className="col l6 center">
          <blockquote><h5>Views: {item.views}</h5></blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="card-action">
      <a href={item.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Link to course</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</li>
);
```

Comment: Have you put the `// @flow` at the begining of your file ?

Comment: @soywod of course!

Comment: What's the error you're getting when you run the flow check?

Comment: @m_callens none both if I change id to string or number and pass a number when it expects a string.

Comment: Can you post the code you use the stateless component?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa just did.

Comment: @EmmanuelHenri Thanks, but I meant the code you use the stateless component instead of the stateless component itself because it's where errors should happen. For example `const something = { item: { /* ... */ } }; <Single item={something} />;`

Comment: What do you mean you are "passing an array of object literals" to this component?